# Is there a way to use ES6 in a blade file and have it transpiled by mix?

Tags: laravel, ecmascript-6, babeljs, laravel-blade, laravel-mix

My blade files often include `Javascript` to improve the user experience. Unfortunately, some of my users are still using `IE 11` which does not have support for `ES6`, and causes my pages to fail with syntax errors. Is there any easy way to automatically transpile all the `Javascript` in blades? If not, should I create a common library that can be called by pages that need particular functions?

page.blade:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
  <input id="field">
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script>
   const a = document.getElementById('field');  // or any ES6 js
   const b = txt => console.log(txt);
</script>
@endsection
```

What I'm looking for is to have babel (or something) transpile that to `ES5` in case my user is running `IE`. If possible, I'd also like to have an `ES6` version and only serve that to a modern browser.